# Nonlinear differential equation $(y')^2+xy'-y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What will be the solution of $$(\frac{dy}{dx})^2 + x\frac{dy}{dx} - y = 0 $$
I tried writing $$z=\frac{dy}{dx}$$
Then $$ z^2 +xz - y=0 $$
     Differentiating wrt x
$$ 2z\frac{dz}{dx} +z +x\frac{dz}{dx} = \frac{dy}{dx}$$
Cancelling $z$ and $\frac{dy}{dx}$
$$\frac{dz}{dx}(2z + x)=0$$
So, $$2\frac{dy}{dx} + x=0$$
Integrating, $$ -\frac{x^2}{2} = 2y+c$$
But this ain't the answer

Comment: Where is the "high degree" ?

Comment: @Mattos Could you elaborate?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I'm not sure, just needed a title

Comment: When you arrive at $(2y'+x)y''=0$, split cases and reuse the original differential equation $(y')^2+xy'-y=0$. Thus, if $y''=0$ then $y'=c$ hence $y=c(c+x)$. If $2y'+x=0$ then $y'=-x/2$ hence $y=-x^2/4$. These are the solutions.

Comment: @Mattos Unfortunately, $z'(2z+x)=0$ implies $2zdz=-xdz$, not your $-xdx$.

Comment: From $ab=0$ you deduce $b=0$. This isn't right...... BTW, this is just [Clairaut's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clairaut%27s_equation).

Comment: If we consider the part $2z + x=0$, then I get then answer $y=- \frac{x^2}{4}$ but that isn't the answer

Comment: Yeah, but writing a=0 reaches nowhere

Comment: @exilednick: how does it "reach nowhere"? as Did shows, for $\frac{dz}{dx}=0$ you get a family of lines.

Comment: @symplectomorphic Using $\frac{dz}{dx}=0$ we get a soln of form $y=mx + c$, but the value of $m$ and $c$ can't be found out here

Comment: @exilednick: please read Did's comment carefully. if $y''=0$, then $y'=c$, and substituting into the original equation gives $c^2+xc=y$.

Comment: True that, I was thinking of a specific solution. But now I derived it from the options. The answer is $y=3x + 9$. Thanks.

Comment: @exilednick: $3x+9$ is not "the answer" to the problem you wrote here, because indeed there is more than one solution; perhaps it is the answer to a different problem, such as a multiple choice question asking "which of the following is *a* solution of the equation." in that case, you should have said so.

Comment: @symplectomorphic Yeah, I had four options

Comment: @symplectomorphic Thanks for your worthy efforts to make the OP *read* what is on the present page... :-)

Comment: What I suppose is that you have been given a condition ... which you did not include in the post. How can we guess it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Completing the square, the equation becomes

$$\left(y'+\frac x2\right)^2=y+\frac{x^2}4.$$

As $$y'+\frac x2=\left(y+\frac{x^2}4\right)',$$

you solve $$u'^2=u,\\\frac{u'}{2\sqrt u}=\pm\frac12,\\\sqrt u=C\pm\frac x2$$

and

$$y=\left(C\pm\frac x2\right)^2-\frac{x^2}4=C(C\pm x).$$

---

Indeed,

$$(\pm C)^2\pm Cx-C(C\pm x)=0.$$

Comment: This forgets the solution $u=0$, that is, $y=-\frac14x^2$ (as explained in a comment posted 15 minutes earlier than this answer).

Comment: @Did: you are right.