# Non-linear Differential equation of first order $(y')^2+xyy'=y^2\ln y$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve 
>   $$(dy/dx)^2 + xy(dy/dx) = y^2\log y$$

I tried solving the equation for $p=dy/dx$ and got:

$$p= \dfrac{ -xy\pm \sqrt{x^2y^2 + 4y^2\log y} }{2}$$

but $\log y $ still remains with $x$ so I cannot apply variable seperable method.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Write $$x=-\dfrac{p}{y}+\dfrac{1}{p}\ln y=f(y,p)$$
and with differentiating, solve the system
‎$$x=f(y,p)~~~~~~;~~~~~~\frac1p=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial p}\frac{\partial p}{\partial y}$$‎

Answer (score 1):

Use $y=e^z$ substitution.

Then: $y'=e^zz'$.

$$(y')^2+xyy'=y^2\log y$$

$$(e^zz')^2 + xe^z(e^zz') =(e^z)^2\log (e^z)$$

$$(z')^2 + xz'-z=0$$

Which can be solved using: [Nonlinear differential equation $(y')^2+xy'-y=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1848484/nonlinear-differential-equation-y2xy-y-0)